# Exclude certain paths from deeplink matching

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack-navigation

I have a deeplink for a screen in the form of `/path/item/{itemId}`(Screen A) and I'm looking to add a new screen with deeplink `/path/item/all`(Screen B).

When I setup Screen B with latter deeplink, it opens up Screen A with `itemId = all`. I was expecting it to open Screen B since it is an exact match. Is there a way to have both these deeplinks in the app and have them open correct screens?

`/path/item/{itemId}` -> Screen A
`/path/item/all` -> Screen B

I'm using Jetpack Navigation with version = `2.5.3`